# Can somebody help me with python-ldap initialize process?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am using OpenSuse Tumbleweed and try to connect my pythons script with an ldap server.

following my code:

```
import ldap
connection = ldap.initialize("*address*")
```

But i got following error:

```
 File "ldap.py", line 1, in <module>
import ldap
 File "*path*/ldap.py", line 3, in <module>
connection = ldap.initialize("*address*")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initialize'
```

I looked up the python-ldap documentation, but the "initialize" functio should exist :/

When i try to install python-ldap, the console told me, that this is already installed.

Can somebody help me?

best regards

Comment: *address* and *path* are variables.
I got the correct ones in code but dont want to share this for security reasons.

Comment: What does `ldap.__file__` say?  Is that the module you installed in site-packages something?  Or did you by any chance create your own ldap.py file?  Perhaps even in the current directory?

Comment: Hello, yes, yesterday I noticed, that I named this file ldap.py und python tried to import this file into themself. Stupid mistake 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake:

The file was named ldap.py an was the only file in this directory. But know, python tried to import this file into the same file.

I renamed it to test_ldap.py and know everything works fine

Best Regards